# Visual Basic find and display

Tags: vb.net, loops, dictionary

I have made a program in Visual Basic. It's a contact book where the user can enter a friend's name as the key and contact which is stored as a value. Both are entered via TextBoxes and the information is then displayed in a ListBox.

The following code is for my search address button where I enter the contact name in TextBox4 and it displays the address in TextBox3. The problem I'm having with my code is that after I enter more contacts into my ListBox and I click the find button it does display the address, but also the error message which is intended to be used if the contact does not exist.

I'm a beginner to programming and looking to see what is wrong with my code.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox3.Clear()

    For Each x In MyAddressBook
        If TextBox4.Text.Contains(x.Key) Then
            TextBox3.Text = x.Value
        Else
            If TextBox4.Text <> x.Key Then
                MessageBox.Show("error")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't shown us how you defined `MyAddressBook`

Comment: Private addressbook As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Comment: It sounds like your search isn't getting updated with the latest set of dictionary of values, although it's displayed in the box?  Where/how do you populate the dictionary?

Comment: Private Sub UpdateAddress()
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

        Dim address As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)

        For Each address In MyAddressBook
            Dim mystring As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", address.Key, address.Value)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(mystring)
        Next
    End Sub

Comment: Please take the [tour].  Your past 5 questions have collected 7 answers, but you have not accepted any of them.  Accepting answers marks the question as closed and helps other users find answers to their problem.  You might also want to browse [ask] since all your posts have a score of zero which means they could be better (for instance code related to the question needs to be in the post, not in comments)

Comment: Your search logic is a bit flawed. Right now, even if it finds an address, unless the address is the last on in the list, the error message will display anyway. Say #2 is a match, and it sets TB3's text...the loop continues to #3 and it isn't a match, well now you've got your error message even though you already found what you were looking for. You've gotta exit the loop once you've found a match, and only display the error message if you've iterated the entire list and no matches were found.

Comment: The problem you have would ***easily*** be seen using the debugger to step through your code.  You'd see the code find a match but still go to the next item in the list and display the error message.  Writing code that compiles is not even half the work; being able to debug code you write is an essential element in programming.

Comment: @soohoonigan any solutions to how i can change the code , currently very confused?

Comment: you dont know how to exit a loop?

Comment: Easiest way: change `TextBox3.Text = x.Value` to `TextBox3.Text = x.Value : Exit For` ...please take Plutonix's advice though, and step through your code with a debugger to see why your problem is currently happening, and why the change fixes it, you'll learn much faster that way

Comment: If thats the level of help you need, you *definitely* want to take the [tour] and accept some past answers to maximize the number of people likely to help you with 101 problems

Comment: @soohoonigan thank you , i will try and make it more understandable to the reader for future posts. Currently very amateurish at this programming business.

Comment: Being an amateur is ok, everyone was at some point...it just means that stepping through the code line by line to see why things are happening is even more important, so I hope that you look into why that change works rather than just copy/pasting it

Answer (score 0):

You probably only need to stop the `For Each` loop when you were successful in your search. Add a `Exit For` after `TextBox3.Text = x.Value`. Since you found the address there's no need to look further.